# ruby 1.9.3 can't use open3 (uninitialized constant ConfigureController::Open3)

Tags: ruby

The project works fine in Ruby 1.9.2, but I want to use 1.9.3.

This line worked fine in 1.9.2:

```
    o, e, s = Open3.capture3("echo a; sort >&2", :stdin_data=>"foo\nbar\nbaz\n")
```

However in 1.9.3, I get

`uninitialized constant ConfigureController::Open3`

Do I have to install the module, or something? thanks!

Comment: Could you post the whole trace back?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Did you `require 'open3'` at the top of your source file? It's possible that before, it was required in turn by something else you were requiring, but now in 1.9.3 it is not. You may need to explicitly require it.